# agregar varios div con .append se sobreescribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy dentro de un ciclo que me devuelve un ajax.
Osea estoy en el .DONE del ajax.

El ciclo funciona bien. quiero aprovechar el ciclo y agregar varios div, dentro de otro div de mi html.
en cada div yo agrego una foto.
pero aparentemente me esta sobreescribiendo todos los divs, ya que cuando ejecuto, me muestra la ultima foto.

no se si .append() me agrega un div, en el primer ciclo, y para los siguientes este me los sobreescribe.
Si es asi no sabria como controlarlo.

HTML:

```
 <div class="carousel-inner" id="fotos">
                   // aqui los otros divs dinamicos                     
</div>
```

aqui en JS, desde el .done del ajax.

```
    let contador=1;    
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                                let nombre = 'imagen' + contador;
                                $('#fotos').append('<div class="carousel-item active"'+
                                    'id="fot' + contador +'"><img class="d-block w-100" src="#" width="1100"'+
                                    'height="500" alt="First slide" id="foto'+contador+'"></div>');
                                if (item[nombre] != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {  
                                    console.log(contador);                          
                                    $("#foto"+contador).attr("src", item[nombre]);
                                    $("#fot"+contador).removeClass("d-none");
                                 }
contador ++;
     });
```

EDITADO============================================

He movido la parte de agregar el div a una funciona externa, y me he dado cuenta que los ("  ") de las class que le paso a mi div daña todo, entonces no sabria como hacer todo eso de los estylos sin que se dañe mi codigo.

```
contador = 1;
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                            adddiv(contador);
                            contador ++;
});
```

La funcion externa:

```
    function adddiv($contador){
    
        // NO FUNCIONA
        var divTmp = '<div class='+'"'+'carousel-item'+'"'+' > hola</div>'; // NO FUNCIONA
 // NO FUNCIONA
        var divTmp = '<div class="carousel-item"> hola</div>'; // NO FUNCIONA

        //SI FUNCIONA
        var divTmp = '<div> hola</div>';  // FUNCIONA
        
                    document.getElementById("fotosCarrusel").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",divTmp);
        
            }
```

EDITADO 2::::::::::::

```
var divTmp = '<div id="fot' + $contador +' "> <img src="#" width="1100" height="500" \n\
             alt="First slide" id="foto'+$contador+'"> </div>';
```

He comprobador que mi div en el CLASS=""  funciona, cuando le agrego CLASS se daña, le puedo agregar el id, el alt le puedo puedo width, etc, a mis divs, pero cuando le pongo el class="" a mi etiqueta div se daña.

Answer (score 0):

En el código que has puesto veo que creas una variable contador, pero no que la incrementes cada en la vuelta. Entonces esta creando todos los divs con el mismo y id y actualizando solamente uno de ellos con todas las imágenes y por eso solo deja la última.

Prueba con el siguiente código (solo he añadido "contador++")

```
let contador=1;    
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
                            let nombre = 'imagen' + contador;
                            $('#fotos').append('<div class="carousel-item active"'+
                                'id="fot' + contador +'"><img class="d-block w-100" src="#" width="1100"'+
                                'height="500" alt="First slide" id="foto'+contador+'"></div>');
                            if (item[nombre] != 'data:image/jpeg;base64,') {  
                                console.log(contador);                          
                                $("#foto"+contador).attr("src", item[nombre]);
                                $("#fot"+contador).removeClass("d-none");
                             }
                            contador++;

 });
```

Comment: Si que pena, se me olvidó poner contador++ en la pregunta, pero si, si la tenia en mi codigo original, muchas gracias, por tu ayuda, este sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Has comprobado que los ids de "fot" no se se estén duplicando cuando añades una nueva imagen?

Comment: ya me he dado cuenta que todo funciona, pero cuando le agrego a mi div,  el class (class="carousel-item active") cuando le agrego eso se daña y solo me muestra el ultimo, le quito esto a mis div, y se muestran todas las imagenes, solo que sin class se ven feas

Answer (score 0):

Ok, he dado con el problema. era algo sencillo pero me tuvo horas y horas volteando.

```
var divTemporal= '<div class="carousel-item active" id="fot' + $contador +' ">\n\
                 <img src="#" width="1100" height="500" \n\
                alt="First slide" id="foto'+$contador+'"> </div>';
```

Resulta que para la class que estaba agregando le estaba enviando  "active",
Esto hacia que todas mis divs quedaran "active", por lo tanto solo se me mostraba la ultima. al ser todas active.

Solo agregré "active" a la primera creacion del div, los demas sin "active" y ya todo se arregló.
Se que es un error tonto, pero espero que alguien le sirva para una proxima comprobar sus estilos antes de duplicar divs.

otra cosa he cambiado el  .append por

```
 document.getElementById("fotosCarrusel").innerHTML += divTemporal;
```

Pero es practicamente lo mismo.